# WiFi control gone after used LAN cable 22.04 + Mate

Tags: wireless, network-manager, internet, mate, lan

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 Mate AND MY WIFI WORKS JUST FINE, when I boot my PC.
Also, when I have the LAN cable connected, everything works fine. However, when I disconnect PC from LAN, I can't turn on Wi-Fi software-wise. The option to enable Wi-Fi is not available (does not pop up and it is hidden while on LAN). Therefore, I can't see any available WiFi networks. The issue gets resolved when I reboot the PC. The problem only occurs when I previously used the LAN cable. Is this a known problem?

I tried:

```
sudo service network-manager restart   (..failed to execute:)
```

> Failed to restart network-manager.service: Unit
> network-manager.service not found.

```
sudo service networking restart           (no effect)
sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager     (no effect)
```

Also tried:

```
iwconfig
```

> lo        no wireless extensions.
>
> enx00051b9a09b6  no wireless extensions.
>
> docker0   no wireless extensions.
>
> vethb08e2a4  no wireless extensions.